# UIScrollview header

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

i am creating a book store Application,so i am showing books in a scroll view with background image(shelf image),i have added bouncing functionality to scroll view,i am adding buttons with book images to scroll view like grid in 4x3 thumbnails

when i scrolled to top the background image is repeating with those shelfs,its ok for me

but when i dragging(bouncing) Scroll view to down its repeating same shelf on the top

**so how can i add any header to Uiscrollview to show like Apple ibooks** 
Can any one help me ..thx in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a header, designate a table view delegate (can be the same as your data source) and give it the methods `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`. From the first one you return the view you want as the header. The second one is obvious.

I'm not sure if that will solve your problem, because I'm not sure I understand your problem or how you propose to solve it.

Comment: thx....but i used image View to scroll view by setting frme likeUIImageView *ScrollBackView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-400,768,400)]; and its working